# Is P(A, B) probability equal to P(A intersection B)?

Tags: probability

I have to study some probability fundamentals for implementing a computer vision algorithm. However, I'm confused about the notation and meaning of P(A,B) joint probability and P(A intersection B). Could you explain whether they have the same meaning or what difference is?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have the same meaning, just notational difference.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, P(A,B), P(A intersection B) and P(AB) mean the same. All of them signify the event "A and B".